# Xpath not getting any value

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, python-requests, lxml, lxml.html

I am using below python to get stock list but its return empty list

```
from lxml import html
import requests
url = "https://chartink.com/screener/stock-closed-near-high"
resp = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(resp.content)
elements = tree.xpath('//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]/tbody/tr[*]/td[3]')
print(elements)
```

---

Out put is:-

[]

Can any one please help to fix this issue?

Comment: Does that website use Javascript to generate page content?  The `requests` module cannot process javascript.

Comment: Hi John , Thanks for youy quick reply. I dont know if this website use javascript or not.

Comment: If you examine the contents of `resp.content`, does it contain the data you expect?

Comment: Hi Larsks, resp.content has huge data but didn't found data which I am looking for. I did ctrl+f to search

Comment: Did you figure it out, or do you still need help?